# Minimal Cygwin configuration necessary to download Android source

Tags: android, cygwin

I am trying to follow these instructions:

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

I have set up a fresh install of Cygwin and downloaded the following additional packages in an attempt to get this to work:

1. curl
2. python
3. git

The command:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

fails with error

```
fatal: 'git' is not available
```

Git is installed and on the path since

```
$ git --version
```

returns successfully.

**Bottom line:** what other packages do I need to install in this Cygwin config to get this to work?

Comment: You should note that these instructions, http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html, mention that building Android on Windows isn't supported. The `git` command on Windows is usually implemented as a batch file, which is probably the reason for the specific error message you mention.

Comment: Building may not be possible, but downloading the source certainly is... I accomplished it before earlier this year and remember it was a painful process (and wish that I had documented my results).  Hopefully somebody else has been through it and if not, I will eventually figure it out again and document here.

Comment: If you just want to download the source, take a look at the `repo` source - if I remember right, it's just a Python script that wraps `git` commands.  If all you're doing is pulling down the source, it might be just about as easy to use `git` yourself manually.

Comment: That is precisely what I am trying to do. It is the repo command itself that fails.  I remember the solution being that I was missing some other package of some sort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running rebaseall on the Cygwin install with the above modules installed is the trick to make this all work!

Running rebaseall can be a bit tricky. The only Cygwin program that can be running at the time is the ash shell. So first of all you need to shut down any long running processes like sshd, close all Cygwin prompts and so on. Next you need to start the plain Windows Command Prompt (if you normally run as unprivileged user but install software as Administrator, then you want to start the prompt by right clicking the icon and selecting Run As… and choosing an administrator account). Then type the following commands (assuming default Cygwin installation location):

```
cd \cygwin\bin
ash
PATH=. rebaseall -v
```

This should result in several lines of output similar to:

```
/usr/lib/xyz.dll new base = 1234, new size = 123
```

After that you can restart any long running processes, start the normal Cygwin shell and all should be good.

Now when you run

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

everything works!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me after spending a lot of time getting it to work!